# jQuery slideUp flashing on iOS

Tags: jquery, slideup

I have a collapsing nav menu made up of unordered lists that uses .slideUp() and .slideDown() to hide and display sub menus. This works great on all desktop browsers. I am having a problem on iOS (ipad and iphone) in which the sub nav will slide up and then flash the child text on top of the other elements before it disappears. You can see an example of this at www.sweetrush.com.

Any idea on what might be causing this or a way to fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried hardware acceleration? It usually solves flickering for me on iOS devices.

```
-webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0)
```

For iOS 6 you probably have to add:

```
-webkit-perspective: 1000;
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
```

Comment: That seems to have fixed the issue. Thanks so much!

Comment: I had the same issue on iPad, and the -webkit-transform: did the trick! Thank you!

Comment: It would be nice if there were more details about implementation of your solution in this answer.