# jquery draggable leaves artifacts behind

Tags: jquery, draggable

I have a draggable pane that leaves artifacts behind when I drag. This only happens on the iPad (not on desktop broswer).

Pane drags from right to left with a vertical draghandle. See link for screengrab.
https://www.dropbox.com/s/weim027bdxg3zva/artifacts.PNG

I've isolated it to the fact that the pane contains a div with a large chunk of text. When the text is set to display:none and the page is reloaded, the artifacts disappear. This scenario is consistent with or without CSS shadows.

Is this some kind of memory issue on mobile devices? how do i fix?

Comment: I am having the same issue, but with jquery slideUp. After the item slides up, pieces of the div are still there, but disappear when I try to inspect with Safari Inspector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This tip seemed to help me with my issue with slideUp on iPad. Try adding the below to the offending element in your CSS.

```
-webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0)
```

I got this from this post: [jQuery slideUp flashing on iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14899609/jquery-slideup-flashing-on-ios)